# SQL JOIN not returning correctly

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please advise why the below sql is not returning the true count of the number of meetings inside the meeting table the employee has had? It is returning a number much larger than usual. I would like to keep all the employees, and return a 0 or null if they do not have any meetings.

```
select distinct emp.employeeid, count(m.meetingidoriginal) as CountOfMeetings
from dbo.employee as emp
left join dbo.meeting as m
on emp.employeeid = m.employeeid
group by emp.employeeid
```

Output

```
Employeeid, CountofMeetings
116         222
118         300
154         1287
```

For example, going into dbo.meeting where employeeid = '116' returns only 6 rows, instead of the 222 which is showing in the sql statement.

Comment: May be - count(distinct m.meetingidoriginal) will help.

Comment: Can you please share the sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft SQL server has a really weird implementation for `COUNT`. You have to say `COUNT( DISTINCT colname)` in order to get the correct result.

Or `COUNT( ALL colname)` to count all values different from `NULL`, not filtering duplicates. That correlates to what any sane implementation would interpret a blank `COUNT` as.

Answer (score 0):

try This Logic

```
SELECT 
    emp.employeeid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN m.employeeid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfMeetings
    FROM dbo.employee AS emp
       LEFT JOIN dbo.meeting AS m 
          ON emp.employeeid = m.employeeid
    GROUP BY emp.employeeid;
```

You Don't Need the DISTINCT as the aggregate function will take the DISTINCT by Default

Answer (score 0):

This assumes meeting table has different meeting ids for each employees, then you could use sub-query and do the `JOIN` operation with employee table

```
SELECT e.employeeid, COALESCE(m.meeting_count, 0) CountOfMeetings 
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT employeeid, count(*) meeting_count 
         FROM meeting m
         GROUP BY employeeid
) m on m.employeeid = e.employeeid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.employeeid, ISNULL(m.meeting_count, 0) CountOfMeetings 
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT employeeid, count(employeeid) meeting_count 
         FROM meeting m
         GROUP BY employeeid
) m on m.employeeid = e.employeeid
```